# How to quantify character values in one column by using a translation table?

Tags: r, translation

I have a datafile and I want to quantify a column from character strings /categories to numbers. I’ve a premade file with about 500 different categories and the corresponding number that it needs to become.

So my first file would look something look:

```
Type_of_fruit
Banana
Apple
Apple
Kiwi
Passionfruit
Banana
Apple
Orange
Etc.
```

I then have a second table which looks like this (translation table):

```
Banana              |          1
Apple               |          2 
Kiwi                |          3 
Passionfruit        |          4
Orange              |          5
Mango               |          6
Grape               |          7
Etc.
```

And want to use this translation table to create a new, quantified column in my original dataframe:

```
Type_of_fruit_quantified
1
2
2
3
4
1
2
5
```

At first I thought to do it with mutate commands, for example
Mutate(Type_of_fruit_quantified = if_else(Type_of_fruit == “Banana”, 1, if_else(Type_of_fruit == “Apple”, 2, etc. etc. 
However, with around 500 different categories in the translation table, that is gonna take a long time. How can I do this faster, for example by referring to the translation table?

To recreate my mock data:

```
Type_of_fruit <- c("Banana", "Apple", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Passionfruit", "Banana", "Apple", "Orange")
Type_of_fruit_df <- data.frame(Type_of_fruit)

Fruit <- c("Banana", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Passionfruit",  "Orange", "Mango", "Grape")
Number <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
Translation_table <- data.frame(Fruit, Number)
```

Comment: `Type_of_fruit_df$Type_of_fruit_quantified <- Translation_table$Number[match(Translation_table$Fruit, Type_of_fruit_df$Type_of_fruit)]`

Comment: Note that ^ will always be faster than `left_join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the column name of the `Type_of_fruit_df` so that all tables share a column name of `Fruit` and then use `?dplyr::left_join`

```
Type_of_fruit <- c("Banana", "Apple", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Passionfruit", "Banana", "Apple", "Orange")
Type_of_fruit_df <- data.frame(Fruit = Type_of_fruit)

Fruit <- c("Banana", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Passionfruit",  "Orange", "Mango", "Grape")
Number <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
Translation_table <- data.frame(Fruit, Number)


> left_join(Type_of_fruit_df,Translation_table, by = "Fruit")
         Fruit Number
1       Banana      1
2        Apple      2
3        Apple      2
4         Kiwi      3
5 Passionfruit      4
6       Banana      1
7        Apple      2
8       Orange      5
```